# Unknown error when inverting image using cuda

Tags: image-processing, opencv, cuda

i began to implement some simple image processing using cuda but i have an error in my code 
the error happens when i copy pixels from device to host

this is my try

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include <opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <stdio.h> 
using namespace cv;

unsigned char *h_pixels;
unsigned char *d_pixels;
int bufferSize;
int width,height;

const int BLOCK_SIZE = 32;
Mat image;

void get_pixels(const char* fileName)
{
    image = imread(fileName);
    bufferSize = image.size().width * image.size().height * 3 * sizeof(unsigned char);
    width = image.size().width;
    height = image.size().height;
    h_pixels = new unsigned char[bufferSize];
    memcpy(h_pixels,image.data,bufferSize);
}

__global__ void invert_image(unsigned char* pixels,int width,int height)
{
    int row = blockIdx.y * BLOCK_SIZE + threadIdx.y;
    int col = blockIdx.x * BLOCK_SIZE + threadIdx.x;
    int cidx = (row  * width + col) * 3;
    pixels[cidx] = 255 - pixels[cidx]; 
    pixels[cidx + 1] = 255 - pixels[cidx + 1]; 
    pixels[cidx + 2] = 255 - pixels[cidx + 2]; 

}
int main()
{
    get_pixels("D:\\photos\\z.jpg");

    cudaError_t err = cudaMalloc((void**)&d_pixels,bufferSize);
    err =  cudaMemcpy(d_pixels,h_pixels,bufferSize,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE,BLOCK_SIZE);
    dim3 dimGrid(width/dimBlock.x,height/dimBlock.y);

    invert_image<<<dimBlock,dimGrid>>>(d_pixels,width,height);

    unsigned char *pixels = new unsigned char[bufferSize];


    err= cudaMemcpy(pixels,d_pixels,bufferSize,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);// unknown error 
    const char * errStr = cudaGetErrorString(err);
    cudaFree(d_pixels);
    image.data = pixels;
    namedWindow("display image");
    imshow("display image",image);
    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

also how can i find out error that occurs in cuda device 
thanks for your help

Comment: Check whether the error is thrown by `cudaMemcpy` and not your kernel  (use `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`)

Comment: Use this command immediately after the kernel to print the errors:

 printf("error code: %s\n",cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First of all be sure that the image file is read correctly.
- Check if the device memory is allocated with CUDA_SAFE_CALL(cudaMalloc(..))
- Check the dimensions of the image. If the dimension of the image is not multiples of BLOCKSIZE than you might be missing some indices and the image is not fully inverted.
- Call cudaDeviceSynchronize after the kernel call and check its return value.
- Do you get any error when you run the code without calling the kernel anyway?
- You are not freeing the h_pixels and might have a memory leak.
- Instead of using BLOCKSIZE in the kernel you might use "blockDim.x". So calculating indices like "blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x"
- Try to do not touch the memory area in the kernel code, namely comment out the memory updates at the kernel (the lines where you access the pixels array) and check if the program continues to fail. If it does not continue to fail you might be accessing out of the bounds.

Comment: first of all thanks aland and phoad that was useful
knowing cudaDeviceSynchronise was useful in debugging
i commented some lines in kernel and i found the error was in index 
till now i get some error in my image but this result is good to me now because i just beginner using cuda

Answer (score 3):

OpenCV images are not continuous. Each row is 4 byte or 8 byte aligned. You should also pass the `step` field of the Mat to the CUDA kernel, so that you can calculate the `cidx` correctly. The generic formula to calculate the output index is:

`cidx = row * (step/elementSize) + (NumberOfChannels * col);`

in your case, it will be:

`cidx = row * step + (3 * col);`

Referring to the alignment of images, you buffer size is equal to `image.step * image.size().height`.

Next thing is the one pointed out by @phoad in the third point. You should create enough number of thread blocks to cover the whole image.

Here is a generic formula for Grid which will create enough number of blocks for any image size.

`dim3 block(BLOCK_SIZE,BLOCK_SIZE);`

`dim3 grid((width + block.x - 1)/block.x,(height + block.y - 1)/block.y);`

Comment: i wrote my bufferSize = image.step * image.size().height also changed my grid dimensions to (width + block.x - 1)/block.x,(height + block.y - 1)/block.y and used step in my cidx but i got unknown error

Comment: inside the kernel, make sure only those threads execute which fall inside the range of the image. The third statement in your kernel should be `if((col >= width) || (row >= height)) return;`

Answer (score 1):

Use this command immediately after the kernel invocation to print the kernel errors:

```
printf("error code: %s\n",cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()))
```